# Creating lambda functions in python that can return objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use lambdas as functions that return objects. Take a look at `lambda x: print(item)` , as it is written, the expected result is that `holder[str(item)]` will store a function that returns the current item. But my code shows that it always returns the last item.

**Why this happens? And is there a way to pass functions that actually return the item?**

```
items = [1,2,3]
holder = {}

for item in items:
    holder[str(item)] = lambda x: print(item)

holder['1'](None)
holder['2'](None)
holder['3'](None)
```

Output:

```
3
3
3
```

Expected behavior would be:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: You can use [`partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools%20partial#functools.partial) instead of `lambda`

Comment: *Every* lambda expression defines a function that returns an object.

Comment: you need to do `lambda x, i=item: print(i)` to put the local `item` in the lambda's closure. You can see that it makes sense that all of them are the last one, as this is the last value the variable `item` is assigned to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools%20partial#functools.partial) instead of using lambda:

```
from functools import partial


items = [1,2,3]
holder = {}

for item in items:
    holder[str(item)] = partial(print, item)

holder['1'](None)
holder['2'](None)
holder['3'](None)
```

Giving an output of:

```
1 None
2 None
3 None
```